# mir session in 16.04 shutdown my monitors

Tags: graphics, mir, unity8

I am trying to test the unity8 mir session in ubuntu 16.04 but when I log in using the session both my monitors turn off.

I installed unity8 using

```
sudo apt-get install unity8-desktop-session-mir
```

My graphic card is (lspci):

```
Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

Can you tip me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in Michale Hall's blog. There is a bug in libhybris that stops mir to work properly.

If you want to try Unity 8 (at least for now) you can follow this instructions:

http://mhall119.com/2016/05/dogfooding-unity-8/